# How to blend two sound files in JYTHON?

Tags: python, audio, jython

So, I am really new to programming, I am currently learning on `JYTHON`, I am required to blend two different sounds and turn them into one sound. I really tried my best to code this so far but whenever I try to play the result, the empty sound file does not play any sound :<

So could you please guys take a look at my code and tell me what did I do wrong?

```py
def blendTwoSounds():
  sound1 = pickAFile()
  antelope = makeSound(sound1)
  sound2 = pickAFile()
  rabbit = makeSound(sound2)
  jackalope = makeEmptySoundBySeconds(9)
  for index in range(0,20000):
    rabbitSample = getSampleValueAt(sound2, index)
    setSampleValueAt(jackalope, index , sound2Sample)
  for index in range(0,20000):
    sound2Sample = getSampleValueAt(sound2,index+20000)
    sound1Sample = getSampleValueAt(sound1, 20000)
    newSample =10.0*sound2Sample + 10.9*sound2Sample
    setSampleValueAt(jackalope, index+20000, newSample)
  for index in range(20000,40000):
    sound1Sample = getSampleValueAt(sound1,index)
    setSampleValueAt(jackalope, index+20000,sound1Sample) 
  play(jackalope)
```

I even tried this code, sounds work but the end result (jackalope) does not have any sound in it. Take a look at it too please and see which one is better to use

```
def blendTwoSounds():
  path1 = pickAFile()
  antelope = makeSound(path1)
  path2 = pickAFile()
  rabbit = makeSound(path2)
  jackalope = makeEmptySoundBySeconds(9)
  for index in range(0,20000):
    asample = getSampleValueAt(asample,index)
    rsample = getSampleValueAt(rsample,index)
    newSample = 9.5*asample+9.5*rsample
    setSampleValueAt(jackalope,index,newSample)
    for index in range(20000,40000):
      rsample = getSamleValueAt(rsample,index)
      setSampleValueAt(jackalope,index+20000,rsample)
  play(jackalope)
  return(jackalope)
```

So it seems like I got this code to work but can I make it better? Any suggestions would really help.

```
def blendTwoSounds():
  path1 = pickAFile()
  a = makeSound(path1)
  path2 = pickAFile()
  r = makeSound(path2)
  jackalope = makeEmptySoundBySeconds(3)
  for index in range(0,20000):
    rSample = getSampleValueAt(r,index)
    setSampleValueAt(jackalope,index,rSample)
  for index in range(0,20000):
      rSample = getSampleValueAt(r,index+20000)
      aSample = getSampleValueAt(a,index)
      newSample = 7.5*rSample + 7.5*aSample
      setSampleValueAt(jackalope,index+20000,newSample)
  for index in range(20000,40000):
      aSample = getSampleValueAt(a,index)
      setSampleValueAt(jackalope,index+20000,aSample)
  play(jackalope)
  folder=setMediaPath()
  writeSoundTo(jackalope,folder+'blending.wav')
  return jackalope
blendTwoSounds()
```